# Getting errormessage only if using function in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I made a function to fetch a column and them render each row as a li.
But I am getting "`Errormessage:`" as result. I tried it without functon and that works fine.

Please help.

```
$nkFetch = function($link){

    $table1Query = "SELECT * FROM table1";

    $res = mysqli_query($link, $table1Query);

    if (!mysqli_query($link, $table1Query)) {
        printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
    }

    $table1 = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        $table1[] = $row;
    }  

    shuffle($table1);

    foreach( $table1 as $row ){
        echo "<li>" . $row['WORD'] . "</li>";
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. Please define "not working". 2. Please don't use `mysql_*`.

Comment: Problem is stated in the title. But I'll edit the post. What do you mean don't use mysql_?

Comment: @RaymondtheDeveloper: He means ***don't use `mysql_*` at all***, not for new code, and refactor the old code ASAP: [read the red box on the doc pages](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

Comment: Dear @RaymondtheDeveloper `mysql_*` [is deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) that's why @Ofir suggest you to don't use it.

Comment: @RaymondtheDeveloper: You say this is a function... is `$con` an actual connection that is passed as an argument, or is it just not declared in the function's scope. If the latter: that's your problem. PS: functions shouldn't `echo`, they should return

Comment: What do you mean with "wrong query"? You have another query and this is in your result, or what?

Comment: I'll try rewrite the code in mysqli and use result.
@dollarVar the wrong query is shown in the html between the UL tags.

Comment: Ok, I got that so far (You should not reference own query error messages in the title). Look into the scope thing and your `$con` as @EliasVanOotegem said, but it seems like that gets through http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php. Do you not get a number in front of the message? ; ) As below the example? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: @dollarVar no this is all I get "Wrong query: Query: SELECT * FROM table1".

Comment: I updated my post.
@EliasVanOotegem I also added $link as an argument in my function now. But is this really needed? Shouldn't $link be accessible without passing the argument.

Comment: @RaymondtheDeveloper: You're not using a regular function, but a lambda/anonymous function! That's a vital piece of information you should've provided us with... I've updated my answer. PS: _no_ whatever variable is available outside of the function should not be visible within that function. JS does scope-scanning, most languages, like PHP do not. Lambda's are relatively new additions either way. But please, next time: post the function in its entirety

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Sorry will do next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**
Given that you're using a lambda-style function (instance of `Closure`), and wish to use a globally available variable `$link`, you should write:

```
$nkFetch = function () use ($link)
{
    //code here. $link is available
};
$nkFetch();
//or
$nkFetch = function ($link)
{
    //code here
};
$nkFetch($link);//<-- pass mysqli here
```

Read [the manual on anonymous functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Very well, I'll bite.

1. You say this is a function. If so: are you passing the `$con` connection variable as an argument
2. Have you made sure the connection (`mysql_connect` call) was successful
3. As an asside: `mysql_free_result` really is a tad pointless if that's the last statement in your function. The resultset should be freed once all function variables go out of scope

Now, here's what your code should look like if you want to use that deprecated extension (BTW: try updating your PHP version, and set your error level to `E_STRICT | E_ALL`, you should see deprecated notices).
Assuming this is indeed a bona-fide function:

```
function getList($con)
{
    if (!is_resource($con))
    {//check if $con is a resource, if not... quit
        echo '$con is not a resource!', PHP_EOL;
        return;
    }
    $res = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table1', $con);
    if (!$res)
    {//query failed
        echo 'Query failed: ', mysql_error($con);
        return;
    }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {//echo here already
        echo '<li>', $row['WORD'], '</li>';
    }
}
//call like so:
$dbConnection = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'user', 'pass');//pass your params here, of course
if (!$dbConnection) exit(mysql_error());
getList($dbConnection);
```

A more modern way of writing this would be:

```
$db = new PDO('127.0.0.1', 'user', 'pass');
$res = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table1');
while($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo '<li>', $row['WORD'], '</li>';
}
```

[Check the `PDO` documentation](http://www.php.net/PDO)